# XML How to add quotes around XName field?

Tags: xml

I have the following XAttribute XElement.XAttribute(XName name):

```
InjuredEmployeeName = e.Attribute("hciIIEmployeeName"),
```

which outputs an employee name such as Doe, John.

What I need to do is put quotes around it like this: "Doe, John"

I thought I might be able to do it like this:

```
InjuredEmployeeName = e.Attribute(“\”” + "hciIIEmployeeName" + “\””),
```

but recieve an error message: "Name cannot begin with the " character, hexadecimal value 0x22."

After doing some research I learned that " is a special character in XML and has to be expressed like this:

```
&quot;
```

so I changed it to this:

```
InjuredEmployeeName = e.Attribute("&quot;" + "hciIIEmployeeName" + "&quot;"),
```

but now I get an error that says "Name cannot begin with the '&' character, hexadecimal value 0x26."

Am I going about doing this the wrong way?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to quote the attribute value, not the attribute name:

```
quotedEmployeeName = String.Format("\"{0}\"", e.Attribute("hciIIEmployeeName").Value)
```